# Close Fancybox Called from A Dynamically Loaded Page

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am trying to close a Fancybox automatically (using parent.$.fancybox.close(); ), but for some reason it is not working because the Fancybox was initiated from some dynamically loaded content using .load() with Jquery.  Is there some kind of special code I need to tag along with the close function to let fancybox know it was initiated from an external source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `load` to display content via AJAX, then `parent` is not needed.  This is because the AJAX content is added directly to the main page's DOM tree. You should only use `parent` if you're loading an iframe and want to close from within the iframe.  If you want to cover both cases use:

`top.$.fancybox.close();`

(This will work as long as the main page isn't displayed within a frame.)

If this doesn't answer your question, please provide more details on where you're trying to close the fancy box from -- from a user-triggered link in the content?  from within a script in the loaded content? from within a script in the main page?

Comment: Thanks, I have Fancybox being initiated from a link in the .loaded content, and the Fancybox contains an Iframe.  After a form is submitted in the Iframe, this is loaded (which normally works on Fancyboxes not initialized from .loaded content): <body onload="parent.$.fancybox.close();"></body>  BTW, I did try top.$fancybox instead by no luck.

Comment: Do you have a full valid HTML document being loaded upon form submission?  Are you submitting to the identical domain?  I gather that you're not using AJAX form submission, correct?  Note - adept use of the console in Firefox or Chrome and `console.log` in your code is the easiest way to solve issues like this.

Comment: I know it would be better for me to use AJAX form submission, but even so would it fix my problem?  Firebug is calling functions invalid from Fancybox.js files.

Comment: Do you have `jQuery.noConflict()` in your top document?  If so, you need to use `parent.jQuery.fancybox.close()`.  "Firebug is calling functions invalid from Fancybox.js files" ???

Comment: sorry, Firebug is saying parent.$.Fancybox is invalid function, just normal functions that are supposed to work from Fancybox.

Comment: I'm sorry, but without seeing your code I can't provide any additional assistance.

Comment: What exactly do you want to see, I have about 5 different pages: header, index, external php (for .load), form, and form_submit.  The pages are kinda long, so I don't want to post EVERYTHING.  I am not quite sure what NoConflict is, but when I looked it up and implimented it, it broke my page.

Comment: In this case (and in every case when asking for programming help) you should post the absolute minimum amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: it turned out I needed to have all of my Fancybox files and jquery inside the file where .close was.  Just for this case, but normally you don't need to have anything but .parent added.